# How do i make a POST requests in a playwright driver ? (python)

Tags: python, python-requests, playwright

i was wondering if it was possible to POST a request inside a playwright chrome/firefox driver, using the **python** version of playwright: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-playwright

---

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: You can certain send out-of-band POST requests using a module like `requests`.  If you mean within the Chrome/Firefox session, then the only way is to click a button that submits a request, or inject Javascript to do the request.

Comment: im pretty sure you are wrong, you can also send requests in the chrome/firefox session , as you can do it in javascript using the playwright js but im not sure HOW to do it in python

Comment: That's exactly what I said -- you'd have to inject Javascript to do it.  You could inject a `<form>` tag with all of the `<input>` tags you need plus a submit button, and then click the submit button.

Comment: oh okk sorry havent understood, so there NO WAY of doing it in python ?

Comment: In Python, you could inject a `<form>` tag with all of the `<input>` tags you need for your POST, plus a submit button, and then click the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Playwright APIRequestContext](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-apirequestcontext) feature.

```
response = await api_request_context.post(...)
```